# Unable to execute sahi scripts using Teamcity

Tags: teamcity, sahi

I have requirement to run sahi scripts using teamcity.
I have done following configurations .
1. Created scripts in sahi editor, created build.xml & pushed code to github .
2. Created project in teamcity & have the following configuration:

- Created new VCS root & added respective github URL.
- Created build step using ant & defined following target -f Build.xml.
- Assigned respective agent to project.

  But when run in Teamcity, its showing success but browser is not getting launched or script getting executed. Hence requesting to provide an help regarding the same.

Comment: can you paste in the build file generated by you and what the default target is? Also, what are you getting in sahi logs? Is Sahi running on that machine where you are trying to run it?

Comment: I got that issue resolved as I was using Build.xml instead of build.xml.But now problem is Build results is not getting displayed in teamcity.

It only shows success & failure but not count of how many passed & failed.

Any one could help me regarding this.

Comment: How is teamcity importing the results? If it is importing just the suite level data, then it will just show the suite status which will just be failed or passed.

Comment: Actually when we run scripts there also it displays Ant build is successful or Failure thats it.It does not show.How ,many passed & how many failed.Hence even on teamcity, its displaying same ant result as Build successful or failure .When we open tool report then only able to see which failed.